# C# - Get the text inside tags using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have used the following code to parse HTML document & store it as CSV file.

```
string actuald=null;
string data1 = File.ReadAllText("E://text.html");
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(data1);
HtmlNodeCollection col = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//pre");

foreach (HtmlNode node in col)
{
     actuald=node.Attributes[""].Value;
}
File.WriteAllText("E://text.csv",actuald);
Console.WriteLine("Data Converted");
Console.ReadKey();
```

in the html document, the content i need to extract lies between < pre > < /pre > .
the content of my file looks like

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>NCEDC_Search_Results</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Your search parameters are:<ul>
<li>start_time=1973/01/01,00:00:00
<li>end_time=2037/01/01,00:00:00
<li>minimum_magnitude=3.0
<li>maximum_magnitude=10
<li>etype=E
<li>rflag=A,F,H,I
<li>system=selected
<li>format=ncread
</ul>
<PRE>
Date       Time             Lat       Lon  Depth   Mag Magt  Nst Gap  Clo  RMS  SRC   Event ID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1973/01/01 06:59:19.23  36.8037 -121.5087   5.65  3.60   Md   28  35    6 0.09 NCSN    1013957 
1973/01/01 07:57:39.65  37.0925 -121.5055   9.19  3.10   ML   45  90    5 0.07 NCSN    1013959 
</pre></html>
```

but in the html doc I have no class specified under any of the html tags? What content should I give in the attributes[""]?

Comment: You need to show the HTML and specify what you would like to extract.

Comment: srry but didnt understand...

Comment: From what you have shown to us, try to use `Attributes["foo"]`

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
i get this error

Comment: Strange.. maybe you have different `text.html` file than I do?

Comment: different html? i dint get that, i have posted my html doc contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get text inside a node:

```
actuald = node.InnerText;
```

To get text including the HTML tags

```
actuald = node.InnerHtml;
```