# How to access nested div based on class name

Tags: c#, html, css, xpath

I have this html code:

```
<div class="searchResult webResult">

  <div class="resultTitlePane">
    Google
  </div>

  <div class="resultDisplayUrlPane">
    www.google.com  
  </div>

 <div class="resultDescription">
   Search
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to access innertext inside divs in diffrent variables
I know for accessing a div with a class I hould write

```
var titles = hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='searchResult webResult']"); 

foreach (HtmlNode node in titles)
    {?}
```

what code should I write to get the innertext of each dive in different variables.TNX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would extend the current XPath expression you have to match the inner `div` elements:

```
//div[@class='searchResult webResult']/div[contains(@class, 'result')]
```

Then, to get the text, use the `.InnerText` property:

- [C# - Get the text inside tags using HTML Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611592/c-sharp-get-the-text-inside-tags-using-html-agility-pack)
- [C#: HtmlAgilityPack extract inner text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785092/c-htmlagilitypack-extract-inner-text)

Comment: is it possible to use `if` in foreach block to determine every of div by tehir class?

Comment: @mary yeah, you can get the `class` attribute value using `node.Attributes["class"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know how many nodes will be returned, I suggest using a list:

```
List<string> titlesStringList = new List<string>();
foreach (HtmlNode node in titles)
{
    titlesStringList.Add(node.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: TNX I will use list. but `titlesStringList.Add(node.InnerText);` just returns one of divs innertext . can I use if to get innertext of each divs seprately in different lists?